# visual studio 2012 can't resolve static fields in a dll lib

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, openexr

I'm compiling openexr2.0.0 using visual studio 2012 x64 dll, I got this error:

```
ImfLut.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static union half::uif const * const half::_toFloat" (?_toFloat@half@@0QBTuif@1@B)

ImfRgbaYca.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned short const * const half::_eLut" (?_eLut@half@@0QBGB)
```

And I looked up in the half.lib using dumpbin /exports: 
[image: half.lib]

Another look up using dumpbin /exports on half.dll:
[image: half.dll]

The two symbols are there. And interestingly, when I remove half.lib from dependency, VS complain convert is also unresolved. This shows that it could find convert but not _toFloat and _eLut. The differences are: _toFloat and _eLut are both static fields, convert is a static method.

```
    class half
    {
        ...
      public:

        union uif
        {
        unsigned int    i;
        float       f;
        };

      private:

        HALF_EXPORT static short                  convert (int i);

        HALF_EXPORT static const uif              _toFloat[1 << 16];
        HALF_EXPORT static const unsigned short   _eLut[1 << 9];
        ...
    };
```

My system is windows 8 x64. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Would seem the method `convert` is implemented in a .cpp file compiled into half.dll, while the variables `_toFloat` and `_eLut` aren't.

Comment: I updated question, using dumpbin on half.dll. The symbols are there. And I'm compling ilmimf.dll. I don't think it needs half.dll to compile a library.

Comment: @Shen this is exactly the same error I'm facing with now. I was trying to compile alembic 1.5.8, How did you solve it in the end ?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to link against `__declspec(dllexport)`-ed symbols.
This means you need to make sure you're `__declspec(dllimport)`-ing those symbols in your project file.
Specifically to *half* - there's a `#define` you can add: `OPENEXR_DLL` that is being checked for appearance in *halfExport.h* and will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Step 14 in the following link solved the problem for me:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openvdb-forum/-jFJQ2N4BGc

In your project, add OPENEXR_DLL to "Preprocessor Definitions" in "project properties->C/C++->Preprocessor"